# How to set up email forwarding from AWS domain?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, dns, email-forwarding

- I've got a domain `myawsdomain.com` on AWS through Route 53.
- I have an email server set up with a different service under a different domain `myemaildomain.com`.
- I have an email account set up for `fred@myemaildomain.com`.

I'd like to have an address `inquiry@myawsdomain.com` forward directly to `fred@myemaildomain.com`. Is there a way to do that with just DNS, or am I going to need an email server running at `myawsdomain.com` to make this happen?

Comment: You'll need an email server of *some* sort. You may be able to point MX records at whoever's running `myemaildomain.com` for you if it's a service like Google Apps (with their assistance).

Comment: @ceejayoz, yes, there is one at `myemaildomain.com`, but will I need one at `myawsdomain.com`?

Comment: That depends a lot on the setup of `myemaildomain.com`.

Comment: I appreciate your help. What other information would be helpful for me to provide in order to answer? I'll modify the post accordingly.

Comment: What service are you using for `myemaildomain.com`? Check with the service's support about having them host multiple email domains for you.

Comment: Ah, so even if DNS for `myawsdomain.com` is served from AWS, I could have the MX record point to the hosting service that provides `myemaildomain.com` and have them also host email for `myawsdomain.com`, right?

Comment: Correct, yes. You can point the MX anywhere as long as the provider you're pointing at is set up to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, man. I appreciate it.

Comment: Would you mind putting this in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: with 12k rep you should know better than to post non-programming stuff here...

Comment: @Alnitak, great point. I didn't even think about it. And the site doesn't help you get the question to the right place...that'd be nice. In fact, the site makes it easy to make this mistake...check out the posts with the DNS tag and you'll see plenty more that don't belong. Further, I just spent 5 minutes looking down the pull-down list of communities and couldn't find one to put this question in. SUMMARY: for DNS stuff, it's pretty easy to make this mistake and actually a bit hard for folks to find the right place for such.

Comment: @JonathanM every so often I look at the DNS tag and go on a question closing spree.  It's unfortunately hard to know when things should go to serverfault (for "professional" admins) and when they should go to "superuser" (or even "webmasters").  They very rarely belong here, though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can point the `MX` records at any provider willing (and configured) to handle email for your domain. Most paid email hosts will allow you to point multiple domains at their service.

`MX` records are separate from your other records, so you can point your `A` at AWS and your `MX` at, say, Google Apps. (Note: there are special oddities with `CNAME`s - they can't coexist with a `MX`.)